# How can I plot different columns of a matrix in a single graph?

Tags: matrix

```
j=0;   
ListLinePlot[Table[u[i][j] , {i, 0, Xmax}], PlotRange -> All]
```

here u is 2 D array and I want to plot all the columns of this 2D matrix in a single graph.

Comment: First I am specifying particular value of j then plot is coming. I want to make it in loop such that i can have plots at various j's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
u = Array[# #2 &, {10, 7}];
u // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccc}
>  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
>  2 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 10 & 12 & 14 \\
>  3 & 6 & 9 & 12 & 15 & 18 & 21 \\
>  4 & 8 & 12 & 16 & 20 & 24 & 28 \\
>  5 & 10 & 15 & 20 & 25 & 30 & 35 \\
>  6 & 12 & 18 & 24 & 30 & 36 & 42 \\
>  7 & 14 & 21 & 28 & 35 & 42 & 49 \\
>  8 & 16 & 24 & 32 & 40 & 48 & 56 \\
>  9 & 18 & 27 & 36 & 45 & 54 & 63 \\
>  10 & 20 & 30 & 40 & 50 & 60 & 70 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

To plot all columns simply `Transpose` the matrix `u`:

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose @ u, PlotLegends -> Range[7]]
```

[image]

To plot only a subset of columns, e.g. columns 1, 3, 6, and 7:

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose[u][[{1, 3, 6, 7}]],  PlotLegends -> {1, 3, 6, 7}]
```

[image]